# Perceptron training in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, perceptron

I am trying to create a simple perceptron training function in MATLAB. I want to return the weights when no errors are found.

Here is the data I want to classify.

```
d = rand(10,2);
figure

labels = ones(10,1);
diff =  d(:,1) + d(:,2) - 1;
labels( diff + 1 >= 1) = 2;

pathWidth = 0.05;
labels( abs(diff) < pathWidth) = [];
d(abs(diff) < pathWidth,:) = [];

plot(d(labels == 1,1),d(labels == 1,2),'k.','MarkerSize',10)
plot(d(labels == 2,1),d(labels == 2,2),'r.','MarkerSize',10)
```

It produces a labelled data set, where the division between the two classes (red, black) are more visible if you increase the number of points for d.

For my perceptron function I pass the data (d) and labels. I have 3 inputs, the x values, y values and bias which is one. Each input has a random weight between 0 and 1 assigned. Note that the dataset d I have named Z in the perceptron function. 
I did use a sigmoid activation function but that would run once through the while loop and always return true after that, the sigmoid function also gave me values of either inf or 1. Below I am using just a threshold activation but it seems to continually loop and not returning my weights. I think the problem may lie in the if-statement below

```
if(v >= 0 && labels(i) == 1 || v < 0 && labels(i) == 2)
```

Perceptron function:

```
function perceptron(data,labels)

sizea = numel(data(:,1));
weights = rand(sizea,3);

Z = data(:,:)
eta = 0.5;
errors = 1;
count = 0;

while errors > 0 
    errors = 0;
    v = sum((1*weights(1,1)) + (Z(:,1)*weights(1,2)) + (Z(:,2)*weights(1,3)));
    if v >= 1
        v = 1;
    else 
        v = 0;
    end
    count = count + 1
    for i = 1:sizea % for each object in dataset
        if(v == 1 && labels(i) == 1 || v == 0 && labels(i) == 2)
            errors = 1;
            weights(1,1) = weights(1,1) - (2*v-1) * eta * 1;
            weights(1,2) = weights(1,2) - (2*v-1) * eta * Z(i,1);
            weights(1,3) = weights(1,3) - (2*v-1) * eta * Z(i,2);
            v = sum((1*weights(1,1)) + (Z(:,1)*weights(1,2)) + (Z(:,2)*weights(1,3)));
            if v >= 1
                v = 1;
            else 
                v = 0;
            end
        end
    end 
end
```

Comment: There are multiple issues when someone is trying to execute the code you provided. Minor: Add a 'hold on' statement between the two plots. Major : I would recommend debugging the second part of the code you provided (the actual perceptron algorithm), so that the variables : weights, Z, eta, sizea etc. are correctly initialized / defined. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There are two major problems in your code:

1. You need to update `v` in your loop every time your `weights` vectors are updated.
2. It seems like you have 10 training set. So you have to update `v` sequentially in the loop instead of simultaneously. Keep iterating for every training set, update `weights`, then use the new `weights` to calculate the `v` for the next training set, so on and so forth, until there is no error (`errors = 0` in your case).

Minor issue:

```
if(v >= 0 && labels(i) == 1 || v < 0 && labels(i) == 2)
```

should be

```
if(v == 1 && labels(i) == 1 || v == 0 && labels(i) == 2)
```

You may refer to [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Example) to get more details of the algorithm.

Comment: I have edited my original post. V is now updated whenever the weights are updated. I have also adjusted the if statement as well but I still seem to have an infinitely running loop. For V should I instead of saying if v >=1  then v = 1, Apply the equation I use to plot the points? I am unsure how the value of v would fit into this equation though, unless I am just comparing the value of v to the result of the equation to plot my points.

Comment: You can change the threshold to 0.5 as the example I showed you did. Besides, you may need to add a loop inside v = sum((1*weights(1,1)) + (Z(i,1)*weights(1,2)) + (Z(i,2)*weights(1,3))); where i is the ith training sample you have. Update v and weight only using one sample

Comment: @lennon310, is this a Binary Online Perceptron?